# How to load 3D object into viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, mysql, 3d, swift3

I have a normal iOS app written in swift. It is not an `opengl` app. I want to load a 3D object on my `ViewController` from a web service. But I have these questions.

1. Is it possible to load 3d object into my existing iOS app?
2. If yeas then in which format should I store the 3d object in my server's MySQL database.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Try GLKView. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/DrawingWithOpenGLES/DrawingWithOpenGLES.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit) is what you're looking for. It can load `.dea` files. They can store 3D data, textures, etc and can be exported from most 3D editors (ex. Blender).